# count values in different rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, count

I have a query that shows Proyects, Date and Estate("Por Iniciar", "Iniciado","Terminado"),
  but I need a query that shows how many of that estates exists, for example a column called 
  Por_Iniciar and show number 5, a column called Iniciado and shows number 1 and a column 
  called Terminado and shows 1, here is my code:

```
select a.nombre as Proyecto,a.fecha_Ter as Fecha_Termino, b.descripcion as Estado from
Proyecto a, 
Proyecto_Estado b,
empresa c
where 
a.id_Proyecto_Estado=b.id_Proyecto_Estado  
and c.id_empresa=a.id_Empresa
and c.rut='96659140'
```

Actually the query shows this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something like this:

```
select b.descripcion as Estado, Count(42) as [HowMany]
  from Proyecto a, Proyecto_Estado b, empresa c
  where
    a.id_Proyecto_Estado=b.id_Proyecto_Estado and
    c.id_empresa=a.id_Empresa and
    c.rut='96659140'
  group by b.descripcion
```